# Remove outliers from a noisy curve

Tags: image-processing, geometric-interpretation

Allow me to present some images so that I may explain my problem. The images on the left contain a smooth curve surrounded by noise.
[image]

Is there any approach that would help in eliminating the noise and retrieving the original curve. Please note, this can be any smooth curve (the image on the right) and equation is not known. No prior knowledge of the curve equation is available.

Thanks,

Sau

Comment: This is probably a better fit for https://stats.stackexchange.com/.. So if there are only one type of points proximity of points seem to be an approach..

Comment: @Rubus Or even [datascience.se](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You can look at dbscan (and I agree with the comments above, that this question is better for a stats/data science forum)

Comment: Thanks all. I will try and post on other SE sites.